# QT+ How to disable bounding rectangle of QGraphicssvgitem?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsitem

I want to know how to disable/hide the `boundingrectangle` of `QGraphicssvgitem`.

This is work with if not implement `QGraphicsitem::Itemisselectable`, but if that not implement then I had a problem to call the `mouserelease` event. so please help me
**strong text**

OK..
I'am currently developing a system using QT of single line diagram designing software. thats' one of main features is drag and drop. left hand side i have a **QDockwidget**. there has QGraphicssvgitems. those things will be dragged to the QGraphicsscene. When the QGraphicssvgitem dropped to the QGraphicsscene,  there displays dotted line around the item now, This is the problem of i have. this dotted line simply turn off if I implement **(QGraphicsitem::Itemisselectable,false)** .**if this implements my svgitem will not correctly snap in to the grid of QGraphicsscene**.  has there any other way to turn-off this dotted bounding rectangle around the item?

Comment: Bounding rectangle is a property, not a displayable element. Or do you mean the frame for the item? It's really not clear what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer.

In your class paint method add:

```
this->renderer()->render(painter,this->boundingRect());
```

Comment: If this is the solution to your question you should click on the checkmark to accept it as the correct answer.